# Setting up a Linear homogenous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Set up a linear ODE of smallest possible order that has solutions $$y_1{(t)} = cos(2t)$$ and $$y_2{(t)} = t^2e^{t}$$,

What i tried,

For, $y_1(t)$ the conjugate solution is $sin(2t)$ hence  it is a complex number with roots of

$2i$ and $-2i$ hence

$$(r-(-2i))(r-(2i))$$

Expanding it, it becomes $$r^2+4$$

For $y_{2}(t)$,

One of the roots is $t^2e^t$ while the other have to be $te^t$ and $e^t$ after

finding the roots, i know i have to find the equation that gives this root and

then combining this result with that of $y_{1}(t)$ to find the original ODE. But

im unsure of how to go about doing this. Could anyone please explain. THanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a second order linear homogeneous ODE, with variable coefficients:
$$
\left|\begin{array}{lll} x & \varphi & \psi \\ 
x' & \varphi' & \psi' \\
x'' & \varphi'' & \psi'' \\\end{array}
\right|=0,
$$
with solutions $\varphi,\psi$. However, for $\cos 2t$, $t^2e^t$, you need a 5th order homogeneous equation with constant coefficients:
$$
(D^2+4)(D-1)^3x=0
$$ 
where $D=d/dt$.

Answer (score 0):

if you have $\cos(2t)$ for a solution, the so is $\sin 2t$ which gives you o homogenous equation $$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + 4y = 0$$ on top of it if you have $t^2e^t,$ then $te^t, e^t$ are also solutions. you can make homogeneous equation $$0=(\frac{d}{dt} - 1)^3y$$ putting the two together gives $$ \left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2} + 4\right)\left(\frac{d}{dt} - 1\right)^3y = 0$$